# Honda Loses All Power, but Starts Back Up

Tags: honda, electrical, accord

1998 Honda Accord EX (Automatic) - Loses all electrical power while traveling (speed doesn't seem to be an issue; loses power at slow (turning corner) or fast (highway) speeds. Flashers come on when car loses electrical power & power steering loses power. Get car off the road, put it in park, and try to restart. Will restart after 3-4 tries, but clicks (starter?) when cranking starter. Has done this today half a dozen times. Is in shop right now, but would like a second opinion. Battery is about 5 yrs old. Alternator? Computer chip?

Comment: First thing is to verify that the voltage coming off the battery and the alternator is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "flashers come on" -- the flashers suddenly start flashing, or it's possible to use the hazard flashers even when the car won't start? Have you tried using a code reader to see if there are any fault codes?

Answer (score 1):

The car is restarting (eventually), so it is unlikely to be a faulty battery or alternator. The symptoms sound like a bad wiring connection or relay.

Cars often click while starting (often the other sounds mean you don't hear the click), so that might not be related to your problem.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a combination of a couple of problems. You didn't state how many miles on your car.  At a starting point I would get a new battery and test the alternator (there's a lot of YouTube videos on this).  Have you cleaned your throttle body and idle air control valve?  This could cause the losing power at low speeds.